# Code does not respond to change in attribute

Tags: netlogo

So I have `aNum` as a patches-own attribute, and in my code I have 
`ask patch 0 -5 
[set aNum (aNum - 1)]` but the patch just has changes its aNum to -1.

How can I make sure it takes what aNum it has been previously assigned and subtracts 1 from that instead?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It does what you expect.  So the question is, why do you not see what you expect.  Finding the answer to that is called "debugging".  One simple way to do debugging is to use `print` statement to help you check the logic of your program.  (Another way is to use `error` to flag unexpected program state.)  For example,

```
globals [testPatch]
patches-own [aNum]

to decrementANum [#patch]
  ask #patch [set aNum (aNum - 1)]
end

to test
  set testPatch patch 0 -5
  repeat 5 [
    let _before [aNum] of testPatch
    decrementANum testPatch
    print (word "before: " _before "; after: " [aNum] of testPatch)
    ]
end
```

Generally speaking, writing such a minimal self-contained example makes a better question.  Most likely, you will find your error while trying to produce the example.